# Function returning module created by functor

Tags: ocaml, functor

I have problems defining the type of a module that is returned by a functor. Could anyone solve this?

```
module type ANIMALTYPE = sig
  val age : unit -> int
end

module type SHIPGENERATOR = sig
  val age : unit -> int
  (* Another possibility: include ANIMALTYPE *)
  val hello : string
end

module RabbitModule : ANIMALTYPE = struct
  let age () = 10
end

module Make_ShipGenerator (A : ANIMALTYPE) = struct
  let age = A.age
  let hello = "world"
end

let get_shipgenerator race = match race with
  | Rabbit -> let module M = (Make_ShipGenerator (RabbitModule)) 
    in (module M : SHIPGENERATOR)
```

**Edit**: Added `hello` to `Make_ShipGenerator`.

**Edit 2**: Added module type `SHIPGENERATOR`, which will include those parts needed from `ANIMALTYPE`.

Comment: You can always check the types with the interpreter. You may enforce the return type of the functor using a module signature or a module type name (`module Mk (A: T): S =struct... ` or `module Mk: functor(A: T) -> S = functor (A: T) -> struct... `).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is `ANIMALTYPE`, what else?

```
let module M = (Make_ShipGenerator (RabbitModule)) 
    in (module M : ANIMALTYPE);;
```

Comment: Even if `Make_ShipGenerator` will contain other fields than those present in `A`?

Comment: sure, you can have more fields, but you can't have less fields.

Comment: It type checks, but field `hello` is not visible. See my update above.

Comment: yes, since you've hidden it with `ANIMALTYPE` signature. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Not sure. But I think I will make another type `SHIPGENERATOR` which the functor will return, and include those parts needed from `ANIMALTYPE`. Thanks!